# jvectormap USA pulling data from json

Tags: jvectormap

I'm trying to insert data into var usa_markers from a json file, it looks OK but data is not displayed on the map.

this is my code:

```
    // USA Map

$.get('map.json', function(data) {
       var usa_markers = data;
       console.log(usa_markers);

    var usa_options = {
        map: 'us_mill_en',
        normalizeFunction: 'polynomial',
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        regionsSelectable: false,
        markersSelectable: false,
        zoomButtons: false,
        zoomOnScroll: false,
        markers: usa_markers,
        regionStyle: {
            initial: {
                fill: Colors.byName('blueGrey-200')
            },
            hover: {
                fill: Colors.byName('gray-light'),
                stroke: '#fff'
            },
        },
        markerStyle: {
            initial: {
                fill: Colors.byName('blue-500'),
                stroke: '#fff',
                r: 10
            },
            hover: {
                fill: Colors.byName('orange-500'),
                stroke: '#fff'
            }
        }
    };

    $('#vector-map').vectorMap(usa_options);
```

});

The code that does work, looks like this:

var usa_markers = [{
            latLng: [40.71, -74.00],
            name: 'New York'
        }]

Comment: solved it... just had to add JSON.parse to the data.

Answer (score 0):

solved it... just had to add JSON.parse to the data